# How to add more zhan two UIBarButtonItem to rightBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I want add three buttons to rightBarButtonItem , but it just display two.

I also try to add a UIView(buttons in the view) to self.view ,but its below the navigation.

[image]

Comment: Please supply some code to allow us to better understand what you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YourViewontroller.h

```
UIView *view_navigation;
```

viewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    view_navigation = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 5, 100, 40)];
    view_navigation.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIButton *add_button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [add_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [add_button addTarget:self action:@selector(Add_Student:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [add_button.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [add_button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 8, 25, 25)];
    [view_navigation addSubview:add_button];


    UIButton *Remove_button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [Remove_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete_icon.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Remove_button addTarget:self action:@selector(Remove_Student:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [Remove_button.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [Remove_button setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 8, 25, 25)];
    [view_navigation addSubview:Remove_button];

    UIButton *Edit_button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [Edit_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Edit_icon.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Edit_button addTarget:self action:@selector(Edit_Student:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [Edit_button.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [Edit_button setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 8, 25, 25)];
    [view_navigation addSubview:Edit_button];


    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view_navigation];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [view_navigation removeFromSuperview];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something Like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                               target:self
                                                                               action:@selector(addButton:)];


    UIBarButtonItem *searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                                                                               target:self
                                                                               action:@selector(showAllButton:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *searchButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                                                                                  target:self
                                                                                  action:@selector(showAllButton:)];


    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[searchButton, addButton, searchButton2];
```

Comment: The question asks how to add more than two. It seems they are adding three but only seeing two.

Comment: The question doesn't mention button frames etc. This is right option to create navigation items. without customisation. The idea in the last line.

Comment: Thanks. Its work with SystemItem, but can't work with customButton.

Comment: Create your own custom button. Maybe with category.